# Cool way to call methods on multiple objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, methods

A long time ago I saw this trick in Ruby. Instead of doing (for example)

```
if array1.empty? and array2.empty? and array3.empty?
```

You could call all of the objects at once and append the operation at the end, kind of like

```
if %w(array1 array2 array3).each { |a| a.empty? }
```

But I think it was simpler than that... or, it could be that. I really don't know, but that's why I'm interested in finding out. Thanks.

Comment: %w() creates an array from the content split by white space. A simple [] array would do here. Otherwise, I think I'm with J Cooper on the all? thing. Even better, checking the above reminded me of the %W() array, which I'd forgotten about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`if [array1, array2, array3].all? { |a| a.empty? }`

I think that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 8):

You can use Symbol#to_proc, if you are using Rails or Ruby 1.9:

```
[array1, array2, array3].all?(&:empty?)
```

Answer (score 2):

J Cooper has it right, but just to add a footnote:

```
%w(array1 array2 array3) # => ["array1", "array2", "array3"]
```

%w takes a string and splits it on whitespace to return you an array of strings

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, Symbol#to_proc can have performance issues, so use it in cases when readability is worth it.